# QuickBooks Online API - TImezone for Timestamps

Tags: datetime, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

When I'm pulling records from the QuickBooks Online API, I'm referring to the MetaData for a few tasks. But the timezone / offset is set to `-07:00`, like this for example: `2016-05-13T20:45:33-07:00`.

Does any one know from experience what timezone they are using or what determines it? And is it possible to change it? I don't really mind storing the datetime in UTC and converting it back when retrieving it, but I need to make sure that the conversion is consistent. So if it's not always going to be the same timezone or offset, then I need to figure that part out too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's all possible answers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9207:00 My bet is they're using the time zone of wherever Intuit has its headquarters. But should it matter? Why not just parse the offset whenever you're handling a date?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm storing these datetimes from QuickBooks in my database, and then using the most recent datetime as a clause in a future query. Basically, I'm trying to query for new records after the last updated record I have. So for instance, I'll receive `2016-05-13T20:45:33-07:00` from QuickBooks and then store it as UTC. But when I'm pulling the most recent datetime from my database and using it in my `where` clause, I need to make sure I convert it back to the correct timezone or offset or else the results will be off. And I'm not sure how QuickBooks handles the timezones.

Comment: If they are indeed using their headquarters timezone, then that should be good enough for me. That would essentially mean that I'm always going to get the times as `-07:00`. I just didn't want there to be a case where I get something else back like `-05:00`, because then I'd be converting it incorrectly. On that note, I have seen someone ask the same question about changing the timezone, and I recall them saying they got it back as `-05:00`.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand correctly, but why not convert the time you're checking against to UTC, too? It seems foolish to *rely* on the offset always to be -7. They could change their headquarters, or DST could kick in.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. That would throw things off. But I have to query against their database using the time values that they have stored. So I can't really do anything with their time values or convert it before querying for it. I hope that makes sense, or maybe I missed something. However, I tried sometimes else out just now. If I leave off the offset, I can still query for `2016-05-13T20:45:33` and get the results I expect. So I can just ignore the offset really, as long as I'm using the correct date and time values. I just need to be able to convert to that format, without the offset.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like I can just ignore the offset. What I'm doing now is, I just take in their datetime values and store them. Storing them drops the offset, which is fine. When I retrieve them from the database, I format them as `Y-m-d\TH:i:s` and I can use that value to query QuickBooks and it gives me the correct results that I expect. Thanks for help and perspective.

Comment: You're welcome - although I'm still not sure I completely understand: it sounds like their database is somehow broken if it's possible to query ambiguous dates/times but elsewhere they serve times with offsets (instead of having it all in UTC). Anyway - it's probably me, and if you feel like you have what you need, all is well.

Comment: This is the closest to a reference to this I've found in their documentation... https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_payments/2_build/20_explore_the_quickbooks_payments_api/30_rest_api_features

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am a bit late to answer, but this is for someone like me who end up here searching for the answer to what exactly is the timezone that Quickbooks Online store its date.

Quickbooks stores date in **GMT** as their servers are located in that timezone.

Reference : https://quickbooks.intuit.com/learn-support/en-us/employees-and-payroll/how-do-i-change-the-time-zone-setting/00/213730